# Laravel : Fill out a form with several drop-down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

im looking from a laravel or html example of fill out a form with several drop-down lists.

Here is my case. I have these inputs-text `name_customer, phone_customer, email_customer`,
I would like that when I select the customer, the form fields are filled with the customer information:(`name_customer, phone_customer, email_customer` from de database).
This what i have done so far.

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>N° Commande</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              class="form-control"
                              v-model="num_order"
                              name="num_order"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>customer</label>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-1">
                              <input
                                onclick="document.getElementById('select_customer').disabled=!this.checked;
                              document.getElementById('text_name').disabled=this.checked;
                              document.getElementById('text_Tel').disabled=this.checked;
                              document.getElementById('text_Email').disabled=this.checked;
                              document.getElementById('text_address').disabled=this.checked"
                                class="form-check-input"
                                id="inline-checkbox1"
                                type="checkbox"
                                value="check1"
                                v-model="num_order"
                                name="num_order"
                              />
                              <label
                                class="form-check-label"
                                for="inline-checkbox1"
                                >Existant</label
                              >
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select
                                  class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                  id="select_customer"
                                  name="select_customer"
                                  disabled
                                  onclick="document.getElementById('inline-checkbox1').disabled=!this.checked;"
                                  v-model="customers_id"
                                  @change="getcustomers()"
                                >
                                  <option disabled value="0">
                                    Choisir un customer
                                  </option>
                                  <option
                                    v-for="customer in customers"
                                    v-bind:key="customer.id"
                                    v-bind:value="customer.id"
                                    name="customers_id"
                                  >
                                    {{ customer.name_customer }}
                                  </option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              class="form-control"
                              id="text_name"
                              placeholder="Name"
                              v-model="name_customer"
                              name="name_customer"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              class="form-control"
                              id="text_Tel"
                              placeholder="Phone"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Adresse du customer</label>
                            <textarea
                              rows="4"
                              class="form-control"
                              id="text_address"
                              placeholder="Address"
                            >
                            </textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              class="form-control"
                              id="text_Email"
                              placeholder="Email"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Libellé</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <label>Date Commande</label>
                              <input type="date" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <label>Date Validation</label>
                              <input type="date" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is pretty vague description of the actual issue you are facing. What have you tried so far, what is your app like? Nevertheless... upon selecting a customer, invoke a data service API that provides you the customer data. Once the api returns, parse the values and fill in the field values.

Comment: So far I am very confused and couldn't start anything because I don't know exactly where to start. But still I'm looking for a way to load in my forms the data retrieved from the selection and the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found the solution to my problem.

```
<select
    class="form-control form-control-sm"
    id="select_customer"
    name="select_customer"
    v-model="customers_id"
    @change="getcustomers()"
>
    <option disabled value="0">
         Choose a customer
    </option>
    <option
        v-for="customer in customers"
        v-bind:key="customer.id"
        v-bind:value="{
        id: customer.id,
        name_customer: customer.name_customer,
        phone_customer: customer.phone_customer}"
        name="customers_id"
    >
        {{ customer.name_customer }}
    </option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="text_name"
        v-model="customers_id.name_customer"
    />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Téléphone</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="text_Tel"
        v-model="customers_id.phone_customer"
    />
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    customers_id: '',
    customers: []
  }
})
```

Here is how you can, after a selection from a drop-down list, fill in the input fields, the data obtained from the database.

You can also consult the vuejs documentation on this subject. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select